# CakePHP 3 : Define global contant variable

Tags: cakephp, global-variables, media, cakephp-3.0, image-uploading

I am working on CakePHP 3 project which is a little big.

I want to keep my application as much clean as possible by separating all media files from core application and that's why I have to store all media files on a separate subdomain as `media.myproject.com` and the project is accessible from `www.myproject.com`.

Also in `media.myproject.com` there could be many `directories` as

```
/root
|- users
   |- avatar
   |- cover
|- services
   |- logo
   |- banner
   |- slides
|- clients
   |- logo
   |- avatar
|- etc
   |- etc
   |- etc
   |- etc
```

Now, to be able to access files in application `view` I want to set global variables that I can use in any `view` like

```
<img src="<?= $media.$mediaUser.$userAvatar.$user->avatar ?>" />
```

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some like this:

**config/Bootstrap.php**

```
Configure::write('Media', array(
        'users' => array(
            'avatar' => 'media.myproject.com/users/avatar/',
            'cover'  => 'media.myproject.com/users/cover/'  
        ),
        'services' => array(
            'logo' => 'media.myproject.com/services/logo/',
            'banner'  => 'media.myproject.com/services/banner/' 
        )
 ));
```

**YourView.ctp**

```
<?php use Cake\Core\Configure; ?> 

<img src="<?= Configure::read('Media.users.avatar').$user->avatar ?>" />
```

Comment: Using `<?php use Cake\Core\Configure; ?>` in `default.ctp` layout does not work however it works on adding it in view files. How could It be used in `default.ctp`

Comment: I am wondering why is define("CONSTANT_NAME","VALUE"); not suggested. When it seems easy, I used this approach in Cakephp 2.x versions