# how to create global variable in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4 and want to create a global variable to store 
some information that can be used throughout the application.

I have tried this code 
in `s.ctp` which is first controller that I am writing

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Controller;
 use Cake\Controller\Controller;
 use Cake\Event\Event;
 use Cake\Core\Configure;

 Configure::write('variable_name', 'Some Value');
  ?>
```

and getting this global variable in `p.ctp` where my code is

```
 <?php 
 namespace App\Controller;
 use Cake\Controller\Controller;
 use Cake\Event\Event;
 use Cake\Core\Configure;

echo Configure::read('variable_name');
 ?>
```

but nothing is shown in `echo` what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `*.ctp` files are for [Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html). Read about MVC, then do the CakePHP Tutorial.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762119/cakephp-3-define-global-contant-variable/37762321#37762321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store this data in [Session Object](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object).

```
$name = $this->request->session()->read('User.name');

// If you are accessing the session multiple times,
// you will probably want a local variable.
$session = $this->request->session();
$name = $session->read('User.name');


$session->write('first_access', true);
$first_access = $session->read('first_access');
```

Comment: i don't want to use session i want to use global variable can you help me  in that

Comment: I think it is the best way unless you want to store configuration data.

Comment: To store config data you should use `Cake\Core\Configure`, if you want to, I edit the question adding an example.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja hey thanks for reply i want to write some values in the variable that is declared in bootstrap.php from s.ctp file and in the mean while i have to read in another controler that is p.ctp, how can i do that

Answer (score 4):

You want to initialise your global variable either in bootstrap.php or your `AppController`. If you do it in the `AppController` you want to do it in the `initialize()` method:-

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    Configure::write('variable_name', 'Some Value');
}
```

You should then be good to use it in your view template as shown in your question.

Comment: public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    Configure::write('variable_name', 'Some Value');
}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'use another controller'. If you want this globally accessible in your app you'd want this in the `AppController`. If you only need this to be set for a specific controller then you can set it in that controller's `initialize` method.

Comment: hey thanks for reply i want to write some values in the variable that is declared in bootstrap.php from s.ctp file and in the mean while i have to read in another controler that is p.ctp, how can i do that

Comment: You seem fixated on trying to set a variable in one template and reference it in another one. That's not how it works. Really, "declared in bootstrap.php from s.ctp" doesn't many any sense. Seems that you need to read up a bit more on the MVC concept to understand how the various pieces come together.